# Getting meta content from get_next_post & get_previous_post

Tags: post-meta, previous

Is it possible to retrieve meta content for the `get_next_post()` and `get_previous_post()`?

I'm currently using the following method, but not having much luck:

```
<?php $prev_post = get_previous_post(); ?>
<?php $prev_post->post_title(); ?> /* Returns content */
<?php echo get_post_meta( $prev_post->ID, 'meta_box1', true); ?> /* Doesn't return content */
```

Should I be forming the call differently?

Comment: According to the codex `get_previous_post()` should return a WP_Object so IF you can verify that the function did return WP_Object and `!empty()` then to me, that looks like the correct way to get the post meta. Are you certain that the next post has the meta set? Are you certain the meta is being saved?

Comment: You're right: your comment made me realized that I was doing a search for meta information in pages rather than posts! Thanks!